# Slope dricore subfloor or not?

Tags: drainage, subfloor, slope

I have half an unfinished basement with sewage stacks sticking out above the concrete. I had used Dricore on one side easily, but this side is with the laundry area, the sewage stacks and the slope of the concrete. My question is if I level the concrete for the Dricore installation, how would water flow toward the drain when there is no slope if the drain is brought up to the level of the subfloor? Shouldn’t the subfloor slope towards the drain?

Comment: It would be incredibly helpful if the subfloor remained sloped toward the drain, but that does depend on the location. Where I grew up, in the mountains, basements _never_ flooded (water table was just too low, and the little rain we got would run right past the house). Here in the Midwest, though, basements flood regularly.